# Alguém sabe dizer como este código JavaScript funciona?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            * { border: 0; margin: 0; outline: 0; padding: 0;}
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function (d, w, h) {
                        var reverseUrl = '//' + location.host + '/afu.php?zoneid=1209384&var=1209384';
                        h.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
            h.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
        })(document, window, history);
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        if (window.top !== window.self && false) {
            window.top.location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com;
        } else {
            location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esse código tem erros de sintaxe. Qual a parte especifica que está com dificuldade ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, há um erro sintático aqui:

```js
            window.top.location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com;
```

Faltou o `'` fechando a string:

```js
            window.top.location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com';
```

Agora, vamos reformatar o código para entender melhor:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            * { border: 0; margin: 0; outline: 0; padding: 0;}
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function (d, w, h) {
                var reverseUrl = '//' + location.host + '/afu.php?zoneid=1209384&var=1209384';
                h.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
                h.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
            })(document, window, history);
        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            if (window.top !== window.self && false) {
                window.top.location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com';
            } else {
                location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Vamos começar com isso:

```
            (function (d, w, h) {
                var reverseUrl = '//' + location.host + '/afu.php?zoneid=1209384&var=1209384';
                h.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
                h.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
            })(document, window, history);
```

Isso declara uma função anônima com três parâmetros e a invoca passando o `document` como `d`, o `window` como `w` e o `history` como `h`. Ou seja, é equivalente a isso:

```
            var reverseUrl = '//' + location.host + '/afu.php?zoneid=1209384&var=1209384';
            history.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
            history.pushState(null, document.title, reverseUrl);
```

O `w` e o `d` são ignorados, a função só utiliza o `h` (que é `history`). Note que ela usa `document` diretamente ao invés de usar `d`.

O nome `location.host` é o nome do site que hospeda a página. Se você abrir o avaliador de expressões do console do navegador aqui e digitar `location.host`, a resposta será `pt.stackoverflow.com`. É óbvio que isso vai depender de onde você estiver hospedando esse HTML.

O `history.push` serve para alterar o histórico de navegação da aba em questão. O primeiro parâmetro corresponde ao estado da página (não é relevante neste caso), o segundo ao título dela (mas os navegadores parecem ignorar esse parâmetro) e o terceiro é a URL. Por exemplo, se você colocar isso no console:

```
history.pushState({a: "teste"}, "Testando pushState", "//pt.stackoverflow.com/teste-pushState");
```

Você vai ver que a URL da página no navegador vai mudar para "https://pt.stackoverflow.com/teste-pushState" e a URL antiga será colocada no histórico. Se fizer isso duas vezes, tanto a URL atual quanto a anterior serão para esse site.

Já nesse trecho:

```
        if (window.top !== window.self && false) {
            window.top.location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com;
        } else {
            location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com';
        }
```

Observe o `&& false`. Ele garante que não vai entrar no `if` e vai sempre cair no `else`, o que dá isso:

```
location.href = 'http://sendtestewebsite.com';
```

Isso vai tentar mandar o navegador para outra página bem diferente.

Agora, vejamos a malícia disso. Quando o usuário abrir essa página, ele será imediatamente redirecionado para outra (sendtestewebsite). Ao clicar no botão de voltar (ou mesmo se clicar duas vezes), cairá na página que tem o `'/afu.php?zoneid=1209384&var=1209384'`. Se essa página for justamente a que está nesse HTML, ele será redirecionado de volta para o sendtestewebsite, ficando preso nesse site.

Esse tipo de prática é no mínimo suspeita, e provavelmente é mal-intencionada. Seus usuários não gostarão disso e irão se sentir irritados com o seu site se você fizer. Por questões de segurança, o navegador bloqueia tentativas de colocar no histórico acesso a sites que não sejam o que está sendo navegado, e por esse motivo, o `location.host` é usado.

Isso também parece ser o tipo de coisa que malwares colocam automaticamente em sites invadidos para redirecionar usuários para lugares onde eles não iriam querer ir.

Comment: Muito Obrigado. Realmente me ajudou bastante a entender esse como funcionava esse código.